# Use visual mode to convert text to unicode bold formats?

Tags: visual-mode, formatting, unicode, font

How can I make it so when in visual mode, pressing `b` will toggle highlighted text to its bold unicode counterpart?

This is what I mean by its Unicode counterpart:

http://qaz.wtf/u/convert.cgi?text=Boat+Programming+should+be+a+valid+SE+Tag

For example:

---

Formatting done with markup

**SE bold**

*SE Italic*

---

Formatting done with unicode

Comment: You may have to use functions for that. For example, `:vmap b :call Bold()` will call the function when you press b in visual mode. Then, you can create a function for it to get the text and replace each character with its bold counterpart if available. You may also try other possibilities like using HTML tags like `<b>` or latex like things. Give an example text along with sample fonts and its bold faced font name. Remove all that is irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a mapping like this so that you can press a key and it will call the function which converts the text for you.

```
      :vmap b :call MakeMeBold()
```

Let's create a function now.

```
     :function MakeMeBold()
     :normal! gv"by
     :let @b=substitute (@b,"a","A","g")
   . :normal! gv"bp
     :endfunction
```

The above code with the substitute function substitutes all `a` to `A` for example. You can copy paste each normal and bold instead of `a` and `A` in try code and use the same line multiple times with different values. A better approach will be to use arrays instead of multiple lines of code.

Put the above sentences in ~/.vimrc

Comment: Since this is mobile, I couldn't practice the above code. Also, I can't use such Unicode characters from my mobile because of keypads. Once I switch to my PC, I will elaborate my answer with more perfect code.

Comment: This is a great suggestion; Once I get my vimrc configured, i'll edit the answer in for others to use.

Thanks.

Comment: Was easy and it worked. It would be nice if there was a toggle ability, meaning this: If (some letters are bold) { All letters are made bold. } else if (All letters are bold) { All letters are made regular. }

Comment: That is also possible. Adding a line of code to inspect their Unicode points or the font will help us to detect and replace with the other one. Once I am done with that, I will add it in the answer :

Answer (score 2):

My [TextTransform plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4005) will handle the setup of a mapping; this will support normal mode command for lines and `{motion}`, as well as visual mode.

Here's an example that only works with `A`; you need to expand the `tr()` accordingly.

```
function! BoldToggle( text )
return tr(a:text, "A\U0001D400", "\U0001D400A")
endfunction

call TextTransform#MakeMappings('', '<Leader>b', 'BoldToggle')
```

You can then transform a line with `<Leader>bb`, or (any) selection with `<Leader>b`.